# How to file for a U.K. income tax refund after you return to your own country?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, income-tax-refund, spain

I live in Spain.

I worked in the UK for 6 months only, being taxed around 70 pounds a month.  I am back in Spain now.

I was told I could get a tax refund for not hiting the minimum. I earned around 8.400 pounds for all my time in London.

If so, how can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Check here https://www.gov.uk/tax-uk-income-live-abroad/taxed-twice

Answer (score 3):

Phone [HMRC](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/hm-revenue-customs/contact/self-assessment). They will tell you the necessary steps to claim back the tax.

---

As an aside, I agree with whoever advised you that you should be able to get a refund, as your total UK earnings for the tax year are below the personal allowance. You will probably need to wait until 6th April before you are able to claim the money back, assuming you were working in the UK since the last 6th April.